# Calculate clustering for each node in graph

Tags: python, graph

Can anyone help me how to calculate clustering for each node in graph without using python libraries? The general formula is `2.0 * E / (V *(V - 1))`.
Code (which is not working properly):

```
def clustering():
        clust = []
        print(vertexDegree)
        E = len(list1)
   
    
    for i in vertexDegree:
        if i <= 1:
              clust.append(0)
        else:
              clust.append(2.0 * E / (i *(i - 1)))
      
    vertex = 1
    for i in clust:
        print("Vertex ", vertex, "have clustering: ", i)
        vertex += 1
        print(clust)
```

**list1** is a list of connected nodes - `[[1, 2], [3, 5], [2, 4]]`

**E** is the number of all connections (edges)

**V** is number of possible connections (edges) between neighbors (nodes).

The graph is represented by a dictionary - `{1: [2], 2: [1, 4], 3: [5], 4: [2], 5: [3]}`, and **vertexDegree** is calculated and saved in the list - `[1, 2, 1, 1, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Conversion of code for networkx to use graph based upon a dictionary instead

Networkx code: [How to calculate clustering coefficient of each node in the graph in Python using Networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58044012/how-to-calculate-clustering-coefficient-of-each-node-in-the-graph-in-python-usin)

**Code**

```
def clustering(data, undirected = True):
  """
    Computes clustering coefficient for each
    node in graph g
  """
  def has_edge(n1, n2):
    """ Helper function
        True if n1 has edge to n2 or n2 has edge to n1
    """
    # n1 neighbors
    neighbours = g.get(n1, [])
    if n2 in neighbours:
      return True

    # n2 neighbors
    neighbours = g.get(n2, [])
    if n2 in neighbours:
      return True

    return False

  def edges_to_dic(edges, undirected = True):
    " Generates graph dictionary from edges "
    res = {}
    for v1, v2 in edges:
      res.setdefault(v1, set())
      res[v1].add(v2)
      if undirected:
        res.setdefault(v2, set())
        res[v2].add(v1)
    return res

  if isinstance(data, list):
    # list of edges
    g = edges_to_dic(data, undirected)
  else:
    g = data

  result = {}
  for node in g:
    # Iterate over nodes of g
    neighbours = g[node]
    n_neighbors = len(neighbours)
    n_links = 0
    
    if n_neighbors > 1:
      for node1 in neighbours:
        for node2 in neighbours:
          if has_edge(node1,node2):
            n_links += 1

      n_links /= 2 #because n_links is calculated twice
      result[node] = 2*n_links/(n_neighbors*(n_neighbors-1))
    else:
      result[node] = 0

  return result
```

**Usage**

Works with dictionary

```
g = {1: [2], 2: [1, 4], 3: [5], 4: [2], 5: [3]}

print(clustering(g))
# Output: {1: 0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
```

Works with edges

```
edges = [[1, 2], [3, 5], [2, 4]]
print(clustering(edges))
# Output: {1: 0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
```

*Explanation*

The reason all the coefficients are zero is:

1. Nodes 1, 3, 4, 5 only have one neighbor, so their coefficient would be zero
2. Node 2 has neighbors [1, 4] but these neighbors are not connected, so coefficient is zero.

**Tests**
[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient)

```
def show_results(edges, text):
  " Show results for set of test cases "
  print(text)
  print('\tUndirected: ', clustering(edges))
  print('\tDirected', clustering(edges, undirected = False))


tests = [
  [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]], # C = 1
  [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [3, 4]],                 # C = 1/3
  [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]                          # C = 0
]

texts = [
  "Case C = 1",
  "Case C = 1/3",
  "Case C = 0"
]
for edges, text in zip(tests, texts):
  show_results(edges, text)
```

*Output*

```
Case C = 1
    Undirected:  {1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0}
    Directed {1: 0.5, 2: 0.5, 3: 0}
Case C = 1/3
    Undirected:  {1: 0.3333333333333333, 2: 0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0}
    Directed {1: 0.16666666666666666, 3: 0}
Case C = 0
    Undirected:  {1: 0.0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}
    Directed {1: 0.0}
```

*Test Graphs*

[image: Test Cases]